# How can I browse my Mac's hard drives with my Android phone?

Tags: file-system, macos

Is there any Android software that can understand afp or browse OS X filesystems some other way
?

Answer (score 2):

Astro File Manager has an SMB module that appears to work for browsing the filesystem via Samba.  I haven't found any AFP or Bluetooth modules (yet); for the latter, Android likes Bluetooth OBEX-FTP but the only server implementation I could find for OSX is ancient and bitrotted.  Android doesn't appear to have any way to do the kind of OBEX stuff OSX wants — although I'd *love* to be proven wrong about that.